# How do I persist login website sessions running in docker

Tags: python, docker, authentication, docker-compose, flask-login

Every time I am release a new build with docker-compose the user sessions are getting destroyed, and the user needs to login again.

I am using flask for backend and Google OAuth for authentication.

Is there any way where I can make the user login session persistent within docker

```
from flask_login import login_user
login_user(user, remember=True, duration=timedelta(days=30))
```

Comment: Do you know less or more how session works and what is needed for them? Like tokens, cookies etc?

Comment: How are you storing the sessions?  How do you redeploy the container when you have an update?